# Weird result afterskip with koma skript glue quesion

Tags: koma-script, glue

I'm currently playing around with the `RedeclareSectionCommand` of the koma-Skript classes. While doing so I stumbled over this:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [
    beforeskip=3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
    afterskip=2ex plus .2ex,
   ]{section}
```

results in this
[image: plus .2ex]

This already made me wonder why the text is shifted upwards while the `afterskip` is only stretchable. Now if I set the `plus` part to `0`:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [
    beforeskip=3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
    afterskip=2ex plus .0ex,
   ]{section}
```

this gets me
[image: plus .0ex]

Can someone explain me what is going on here? Maybe I still don't completely understand glue (I thought by specifying `plus` I make the dimension stretchable, but in my case the dimension somehow shrinks)

Full Working Example (not quite sure if it's minimal):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,headings=normal,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol}

\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [
    beforeskip=3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
    afterskip=2ex plus .0ex,
   ]{section}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\

\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\

\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\

\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\

\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\

\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be to use a positive `beforeskip` with negative stretch and shrink values. Using a negative `plus` and `minus` value, IMHO makes only sense with also a negative default value, e.g., `-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex`. Maybe, you've not read the special meaning of the sign to the values of `beforeskip` and `afterskip` with the default `afterindent=bysign` and `runin=bysign`. See the KOMA-Script manual for this information. But you even don't need to know the special meaning, if you just overwrite the default of variables `afterindent` and `runin`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,headings=normal,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol}

\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [
    runin=false,
    afterindent=false,
    beforeskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
    afterskip=2ex plus .2ex,
   ]{section}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\

\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\

\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\

\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\

\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\

\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: You should not use `\\`  in the normal text. Always use paragraphs. If you don't want indented paragraphs, read option `parskip` in the manual and maybe: [How to correctly prevent paragraph indentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_NoParIndent/) (also [available in German](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_NoParIndent/)).

Comment: Ah alright. Tbh I didn't had a closer look at `beforeskip` (just took it from `komacv` as I'm experimenting with this one) as the issue occured when changing the `afterskip` dimension. Please use `afterskip=2ex plus .2ex,` in your solution as with `plus .0ex` the issue didn't occur in the first place as well. I'll have to think about what the original dimension specification was trying to achieve.

Comment: @atticus Using `afterskip=2ex plus .2ex` instead of `afterskip=2ex plus 0ex` does not change a lot, because the main problem was the `beforeskip`, that didn't make sense. Nevertheless, I've changed my example and the screenshot.